# How to Convert special characters into Symbol in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have some Special characters in in my mysql database..but i want to conver that into correspond symbol of that charater.. Ä this is the charater and the correspond symbol is Đ .
How i can convert this in php or mysql?

Comment: What is the relationship between a "character" and its "symbol"?

Comment: Your question is missing technical information useful in answering it. I suggest you make yourself more comfortable with encodings in webapplications, for example see: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) - BTW it is highly likely that your question has many many answers already on this website. Please do your research before posting a question! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try it: `http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php`

This function decodes data, assumed to be UTF-8 encoded, to ISO-8859-1.

Or: `htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`